# Will a process with mean step 0 cross every bound infinitely often?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Take a discrete time process with mean step size 0. The steps will take values > ε with positive probability.

It seems intuitive that, for any bound, the process will cross the bound infinitely many times.  Does anyone know of a result that says this?

Comment: Suppose all steps are even.  Then you never hit odd values.

Comment: Oops sorry.  I meant cross every bound i.o.  I was getting it confused with Brownian motion which does hit every point.